# Magento error magento SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have been setting up a Magento (1.9.x) site for a couple of months. Most of the products have been added using the built-in import functionality. I have also used import and dataflow profiles to update items such as pricing, cost, and attributes. I have the Amasty product management products installed (product grid editing, etc.).

Just in the last two days, when I edit an existing product from the back end, I am getting the error below. It also occurs editing an item that I have just added (the Add works, but the edit throws the error). The product changes are not saved. I can edit item attributes (name, price, categories) from the Amasty product and they save. Is there a fix for this?

**magento SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`, `use_config_backorders`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `is_decimal_divided`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when attempting to add a new product. Using Magento 1.9. Before that I had added a virtual product. I deleted the virtual product and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem: I had added an attribute named "stock_item." As long as this attribute was in an attribute set, the item would throw the error. I removed it from test attribute sets and noted that the items in these attribute sets would save. When I re-added the item with the key "stock_me," all items seem to save without error.